# Create 1D Numpy "Array-Like" Object from a Pandas Dataframe with Multiple Columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Regards,

I have a Pandas dataframe, "df", with 7 columns of the z-scores of 7 different variables.

I would like to convert that Pandas dataframe, 'df' into a **1D** **array-like** object -- not just an ordinary numpy array. So, the "df.values" command doesn't suffice in this instance.

What do I do in this instance? I am very lost.

Why do I need a 1D array-like object?

I would like to use it as an input to a scipy function for combining the z-scores using the Stouffer method. Details: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.combine_pvalues.html

Please, help.

Comment: Can you put a example of the result? and, show your code please.

Comment: Maybe could transform to numpy matrix and then transform to 1D matrix??

Comment: what is `df.values.shape` now?

Comment: @ Daniel F The shape is (498, 9)